# Unable to install Ruby on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install ruby 3.0 with Homebrew.

```
brew install ruby
```

But I am getting an error

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "ruby".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

When I try 'brew search ruby', I get this:

```
==> Formulae
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-libyaml
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ncurses
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-readline
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-zlib
==> Casks
rubymine                                 rubymotion
```

I tried uninstalling homebrew and reinstalling it and also used `brew cleanup`. Nothing worked.
Also, my MacOS version is 11.2.3 (20D91) MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: What does `brew search ruby` return ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) which I Homebrew can install: `brew install rbenv`

Comment: Hey @tadman I am getting the same "No formulae found" error when I use `brew install rbenv`

Comment: Sounds like your `brew` is broken. `brew doctor` or just reinstall it.

Comment: I ran brew doctor and I got a couple of warnings. I already reinstalled brew twice though. Is it a problem in my MacOS?

Comment: It just seems odd that it's not finding such basic things. Is there some kind of firewall restriction preventing it from pulling down the package info? If I do `brew search ruby` I get a whole bunch of options using Homebrew 3.0.10-35-gab99855.

Comment: I disabled my firewall and tried again... it doesn't work. There is something saying `fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision` though. Could it be the problem?

Comment: You may need to clear out the brew cache and pull down again with a `brew update`. It sounds like something's messed up locally. Check where that is with `brew --cache`.

Comment: `brew update` returned 'Already up-to-date' and `brew --cache` returned `/Users/my_name/Library/Caches/Homebrew`. I also cleared it out.

Comment: I got it working after clearing cache and updating a few times :) Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: for anyone still, having this problem I just solved it using this https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2769#discussioncomment-1956665 (`rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" && brew tap homebrew/core`)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and ran brew doctor which gave me this message:

```
Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core
```

Try running brew doctor and see if you get the same.

I followed the instructions and yah! I have ruby!

Comment: I think the current version ruby installed by brew is 3.2.0 btw

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer for your question, but an alternate approach, and one I recommend following when using languages like Ruby and Python, where you often need multiple different versions installed simultaneously, along with the ability to switch between them as you move between projects: use a tool like [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

If `brew` cannot find/install the version you need, `rvm` will download and build it from source, and then you can switch between versions with `rvm use <version>`.  When I was doing a lot of ruby dev some years back I found it indispensable, and it's going to be a faster way to stay current than waiting on homebrew to keep pace, generally.

(edit) Other functionally similar tools include `rbenv` and `chruby`.